# chart.js labels text font size and digits text font size too small

Tags: chart.js

I would like to increase the size of the following elements. Could you please edit the code below to make these elements bigger:

- the label text size (the NaCl and SalinityDrift boxes above the
  chart)
- the numbers themselves in x,y,y2 axes

Script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/1.1.1/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myChart").width( $(window).width() *0.97 );
    $("#myChart").height( $(window).height() * 0.8 );

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    const options = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'NaCl',
                    data: natriumChrolideData,
                    borderColor: 'blue',
                    yAxisID: 'y',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Salinity drift',
                    data: salinityDriftData,
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    yAxisID: 'y2',
                },                
            ]
        },
        options: {
            parsing: false,
            normalized: true,
            animation: false,
            responsive: false,
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Time (client time zone)',
                        font: {
                            size: 24
                        }
                    },
                },
                y: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'NaCl storage, kg',
                        font: {
                            size: 24
                        }
                    }
                },
                y2: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Salinity drift, %',
                        font: {
                            size: 24
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                        },
                    }
                },
            },
            plugins: {
                zoom: {
                    pan: {
                        enabled: true,
                        onPanStart({chart, point}) {
                            // alert("pan works!");
                        },
                        mode: 'x',
                    },
                    zoom: {
                        wheel: {
                            enabled: true,
                        },
                        pinch: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        mode: 'x',
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }

    new Chart(ctx, options);
</script>
```

Produced plot example:
[image]

Note: I found some solutions to use `fontSize` or `tick.font` or `tick.fontSize`, but either I implemented them wrongly or they do not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the `ticks` config in the scale title while its supposed to be on the root of the scale itself. Also for the boxes font size on top you need to configure it in the `options.plugins.legend.labels` namespace.

Live example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          font: {
            size: 20
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          font: {
            size: 20
          }
        }
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
          font: {
            size: 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```